# python nested list: replace repeated items in nested list while retaining first occurrence

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list of lists and want to replace all the occurrences of the same word within the entire list/matrix with a dash except the first occurrence. I have created a separate list that has a count of how many of each element is in the original list of lists. I want the first occurrence of the word to be replaced by the item in the count list so the number is there.

```
table = [['Bacteria', 'Aquificae', 'Persephonella'],
        ['Bacteria', 'Aquificae', 'Thermovibrio'],
        ['Bateria', 'Firmicutes', 'Bacillus']]
countlist = ['Bacteria3', 'Aquificae2', 'Persephonella1', 'Thermovibrio1', 'Firmicutes1', 'Bacillus1']
```

So I want the list to be like this when I'm done:

```
table = [['Bacteria3', 'Aquificae2', 'Persephonella1'],
        ['-', '-', 'Thermovibrio1'],
        ['-', 'Firmicutes1', 'Bacillus1']]
```

I want to put this into a tab delimited table after so it won't look so confusing in the end.

This is what I have currently for replacing the word with the count list version but is not working:

```
for num in range(1525):
    for n in table[num]:
            for s in count:
                    if n in s:
                            n = s
```

**EDIT**
Working in Python 2.6.1

Comment: This looks like a bad idea for a data structure. Why mix the number into the name of the species? Also, in Python you don't usually use `for ... in range()` loops but rather iterate over the structures directly.

Comment: It is important to use the appropriate tools for this task, for the sake of speed and maintainability.  You can store occurances in a dictionary `{name: num_of_occurances}` and then output your table any way you choose fit.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, to iterate over structures directly do you mean something like `for i in range(len(a)):`?
@dm03514 With a dictionary would I be able to maintain that the columns are subgroups of the previous columns? ie aquificae and firmicutes are subgroups of bacteria. I thought dictionaries had only associated keys but were otherwise random in order so the relationship would be lost.

Comment: No, you can simply do `for item in a`.

Comment: See edit following your request to work with Python 2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with all that is said in the comments and other answers on the data structure. I only add this answer as it provides a way of getting the table in the format requested by the OP.

*EDIT commented out the use of Counter so as to allow this to work on Python 2.6*

```
# from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

table = [['Bacteria', 'Aquificae', 'Persephonella'],
        ['Bacteria', 'Aquificae', 'Thermovibrio'],
        ['Bacteria', 'Firmicutes', 'Bacillus']]

# count_dict = Counter( [ item for row in table for item in row   ] )

count_dict = {}
for row in table:
    for item in row:
        count_dict[item] = count_dict.get(item, 0) + 1

for index_row, row in enumerate(table):
    for index_col, element in enumerate(row):
        if element in count_dict:
            table[index_row][index_col] = '%s %s' % (element, count_dict[element])
            del count_dict[element]
        else:
            table[index_row][index_col] = '-'

pprint(table)
```

which produces:

```
[['Bacteria 3', 'Aquificae 2', 'Persephonella 1'],
 ['-', '-', 'Thermovibrio 1'],
 ['-', 'Firmicutes 1', 'Bacillus 1']]
```

Comment: I was writing an edit with almost an identical solution in case they wanted the table like this-- I'll stop now :)

Comment: I tried this and is probably what I would like but I just discovered I am working in python 2.6.1... Any suggestions?

Comment: This should have removed the parts inaccessible to Python 2.6.1

Comment: Thank you!! this was exactly what I was requesting!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if your table with dashes in is required, or just a step you think you need to get to the tab delimitated table, this code will get a list with names appended with totals that can be used to make the tab delimitated table

```
from collections import Counter
count= Counter([item for sublist in table for item in sublist])
totals= ["%s%i"%(e,c) for e,c in count.most_common()]

#can then be tab deliminated
"\t".join(totals)
```

Comment: I tried this and is probably what I would like but I just discovered I am working in python 2.6.1...So the Counter isn't available. Any suggestions? The dashes are not necessary if the output without them is not confusing.